Reconstructing Source Code for a scratch-built GIS system
I have a new client who wants to move their GIS platform support to a new vendor.  The only problem is the outgoing vendor of 15 years does not want to release the source code.  My client made a mistake by outsourcing all their knowledge on their own platform.
I believe this platform is developed in Java.  I have ability to access the production systems.  I will have all permissions to read and copy files.
What options do I have to leverage my access to reconstruct the source code?  Do I need to reconstruct it?
When I take this platform over, I need to be sure that I am able to deliver CRs and ongoing support to my clients' end customers so its very important I also have full understanding of the data flows.  What tools and methodologies can I use?

You do know that this may be explicitly against the signed contract and therefore something you may want to consult with the legal department first?

already verified with Legal that client owns the source code. They just dont have access to it due to vendor defiance

Sounds like a law suit right there. You may want to get there first.  Ud written in java there are plenty of decompilers.  Given you have to ask you may want to hire a consultant to do this efficiently in the first try.

_ I believe this platform is developed in Java_ - why aren’t you certain?
